# How to predicting the next date with Python ML

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, prediction

I have a list of dates around 10 dates in asc order. These are the dates a buidling was open. I need to predict the next date using this. I tried scikit learn like below

```
import datetime
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

dates = available_dates

# Convert dates to datetime.datetime objects
datetime_dates = [datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.datetime.min.time()) for date in dates]

# Create X and y for regression
X = [[date.timestamp()] for date in datetime_dates]
y = list(range(1, len(dates) + 1))

# Create a linear regression model
regression_model = LinearRegression()

# Fit the model to the data
regression_model.fit(X, y)

# Predict the next date when the house will become available
next_date_timestamp = regression_model.predict([[datetime_dates[-1].timestamp() + 24 * 60 * 60]])
next_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(next_date_timestamp[0])

print("Next available date:", next_date.date())
```

Next date always comes as 1969-12-31

Is this because the dataset is too small?

Should I use something else? Or I can fix this somehow?

I am a complete noob to ML stuff and I have an urgent deadline :(. Pls help me with what tech to use or what to Google. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

So LinearRegression is essentially just trying to predict a line, y = mx + b. In your case, you’re feeding it y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], so once you’ve fit your model, when you call predict it’s going to return a very small number somewhere between 0 and 9 most likely. Then you feed this into timestamp and add 24 * 60 * 60, and interpret this as a date. Python (and other languages) interpret timestamp 0 as  January 1st, 1970, so the timestamp you get back from LinearRegression is going to be somewhere in this neighborhood.
It's entirely possible to use LinearRegression if you can formulate your problem as a line, i.e. y=mx+b, but I’d suggest an easier approach to get started. Instead of using LinearRegression, you can find the average differences between your last two times, add that to your last time, and use that as a first order prediction. A second order prediction would use the average of your last two differences, and so on.

This would look something like the following:

```
dates = []
dates.append(datetime.datetime(2004, 2, 4))
dates.append(datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 5))
dates.append(datetime.datetime(2006, 4, 6))
diff = dates[2].timestamp()- dates[1].timestamp()
dates[2].timestamp() + diff
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dates[2].timestamp() + diff, tz=None)
```

will return datetime.datetime(2007, 5, 7, 23, 0).
Note that this is a very simplistic approach, there are a ton of more sophisticated ways to approach time series data (google SARIMAX for example), but should give you enough to get started. hth.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the value of 1 to the time that the house is available and the value of -1 to the time that's not available. This would be your "y". Your X should be the timestamps but use the pandas to_datetime (or something similar, not sure off the top of my head). Now you can give new timestamps (future) to predict whether the house is available (1) or not (-1).